# sql server usage IF NOT EXISTS in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is there is something wrong in my sql Query ? 
I am having an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.

```
  protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                //string prNB = Session["prnb"].ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PrescTest(Test, idPresc)select @Test, idPresc from Prescription where prNB = @prNB and not exists(select test from PrescTest pt,join Prescription p on pt.idPresc = p.idPresc where prNB = @prNB)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Test", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[2].Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("prNB", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Session["prnb"].ToString();
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("PrescForm.aspx");
    }
```

Sql tables diagram:

[image]

Comment: So, you already know how to use parameters in sql, but still do string concatenation. Why?

Comment: Should parameters not always start with `@` ?

Comment: @GuidoG OP is doing a mix of parameters and string concatenation.

Comment: Hope is just a test and that prNB is going to go later on a parameter, because it smells like sql injection from here.

Comment: @Kaitiff it is stored in SessionState, which is server side, lets hope before storing the data in Session it was validated. If the variable was client side recieved (QueryString, form parameters,...) it would be much worse indeed

Comment: @GuidoG yes but prNB is not considered a parameter here

Comment: @MonicaKhoury "prNB is not considered a parameter here". Maybe it would be nice making it a parameter. Both for extra security and SQL Server performance (only 1 execution plan)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things wrong in your sql statement.

- the usage of string concatenation instead of a parameter.
- the usage of implicit (old style) join. Explicit joins are a part of Ansi-Sql for well over 25 years now (approaching 30, I believe) so there really is no excuse to write implicit joins.
- the usage of a subquery inside the values clause - instead of simply `insert...select`.
- the fact that you run this query for every row in your grid, instead of collecting the data from the grid into a collection and run a single `insert...select` statement
- the `begin` and `end` keywords define a code block, much like `{` and `}` in c# - the open parenthesis right after the `begin` keyword is a redundant (and I think also a syntax error). same goes for the close parenthesis after the `end` keyword

A quick fix of your SQL statement is this:

```
insert into PrescTest (Test,idPresc) 
select @Test, idPresc 
from Prescription 
where prNB = @prNB
and not exists(
    select test 
    from PrescTest pt 
    join Prescription p 
        on pt.idPresc = p.idPresc
    where prNB = @prNB 
)
```

Note that the `not exists` have moved into the where clause so there really is no need for the `if`.

Please note that this doesn't address the fact that you are running this sql for each row individually - you should look up table valued parameters to fix that issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I tried it now and it gave me an incorrect syntax near the keyword join...

Comment: I updated to code above please if u can take a look at it

Comment: Sorry, I somehow failed to remove the comma right after `pt`. Editing my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query. It will work

```
if not exists(select test from PrescTest pt, Prescription p where prNB ="+ prNB +"and pt.idPresc = p.idPresc) begin insert into PrescTest (Test,idPresc) values (@Test,(select idPresc from Prescription where prNB=" + prNB + "))end
```

Comment: This solves only one of many problems in the OP's code, and doesn't address the most significant issue which is the SQL Injection threat.

Answer (score 0):

Two missing closing parenthesis before the "end"?

```
... + prNB + "))end))", conn);
```

Comment: There's also a missing space before `and` (if you go down the string concatenation route)